# How to scrape webpage of items, each item has link to new page

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, pagination, scrapy

I'm creating a web scraper with scrapy and python. The page I'm scraping has each item structured as a card, I'm able to scrape some info from these cards (name, location), but I also want to get info that is reached by clicking on card > new page > click button on new page that opens form > scrape value from the form. How should I structure the parse function, do I need nested loops or separate functions ..?

```
class StackSpider(Spider):
    name = "stack"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ["example.com/page"]
    def parse(self, response):
        for page_url in response.css('a[class ~= search-  card]::attr(href)').extract():
            page_url = response.urljoin(page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=page_url, callback=self.parse)

        for vc in response.css('div#vc-profile.container').extract():
            item = StackItem()
            item['name'] = vc.xpath('//*[@id="vc-profile"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/h1/text()').extract()
            item['firm'] = vc.expath('//*[@id="vc-profile"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/h2/text()[1]').extract()
            item['pos'] = vc.expath('//*[@id="vc-profile"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/h2/text()[2]').extract()
            em = vc.xpath('/*[@id="vc-profile"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/button').extract()
            item['email'] = em.xpath('//*[@id="email"]/value').extract()
            yield item
```

the scraper is crawling, but outputting nothing

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is creating an item object on the first page, scrape the needed data and save to the item. Again make a request to the new URL (`card > new page > click the button to form`) and pass the same item in there. Yielding the output from here will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably split the scraper into 1 'parse' method and 1 'parse_item' method.
Your parse method goes through the page and yields the urls of the items for which you want to get the details. The parse_item method will get back the response from the parse function, and get the details for the specific item.
Difficult to say what it will look like without knowing the website, but it'll probably look more or less like this:

```
class StackSpider(Spider):
    name = "stack"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ["example.com/page"]
    def parse(self, response):
        for page_url in response.css('a[class ~= search-  card]::attr(href)').extract():
            page_url = response.urljoin(page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=page_url, callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response)
        item = StackItem()
        item['name'] = vc.xpath('//*[@id="vc-profile"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/h1/text()').extract()
        item['firm'] = vc.expath('//*[@id="vc-profile"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/h2/text()[1]').extract()
        item['pos'] = vc.expath('//*[@id="vc-profile"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/h2/text()[2]').extract()
        em = vc.xpath('/*[@id="vc-profile"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/button').extract()
        item['email'] = em.xpath('//*[@id="email"]/value').extract()
        yield item
```